# mediaplayer gets hanged

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, emulation

My list consists of 12 songs and it has to move in an infinite loop when the button is clicked.my mediaplayer is working fine in emulator but it is getting stuck if i press the button continuously for 32 times in htc mobile.

```
         public void onClick(View v) 

        {
            if(count==listlen)
                count=-1;
            if(count<listlen)
            {
             count=count+1;
            }
             loadpitch(concatstr);
         }
```

load pitch has this

```
                      try
                        {  
                        if(sp.isChecked()||sm.isChecked())
                        {

                            mp.reset();
                            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
                            mp.setLooping(true);
                        }
                        if(play==true)
                        {
                          mp.start();
                        }
                    }
```

where listlen is the length of the pre-defined list
loadpitch is function which loads the song
sp and sm are toggle buttons!

Comment: post your mediaplayer code also. what you're showing isn't going to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

check this way for ur media player while starting media player onclick

```
        if (mPlayer!=null) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            }
        mPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this,song);
        mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Agreed. I remember writing code to loop through songs before as well and ended up recreating the MediaPlayer too.